# How to add a column in the data frame within a function

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and I want to do some calculation with existing columns and create new column in my data set which is a combination of existing... I can do this easily outside function... but if I wrap the code witin function, the changes I made (inside functions) are not visible outside function... i.e. the new column doesn't exist...

I would appreciate sample code to do this...

Comment: It would help to know what software you're using, and to see a minimal example where things go wrong.

Comment: if it is about R you need to return new values out of functions either by `return(data_frame_I_work_with)` or `return(column_I_made)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll assume it is about R... R does not pass arguments by reference (environments and reference classes (S5) are an exception, but this is out of the current range of abstraction). Thus, when you write

```
addThree<-function(x){
 x<-x+3
}
4->y
addThree(y)
```

`y` is still 4 at the end of code, because inside the function, `x` is the fresh copy of `y`s value, not the `y` itself (again, not exactly, but those are higher order details).

Thus, you must adapt to R's pass-by-copy scheme and return the altered value and assign it back to your variable (using old wording, there are no procedures in R):

```
addThree<-function(x){
 return(x+3)
}
4->y
addThree(y)->y
#y is now 7
```

Don't worry, this works smoothly for even more complex objects because R is garbage-collected and has lazy evaluation.

BTW, you can omit `return` if you want to return the last value produced in function, i.e. `addThree`'s definition may look like this:

```
addThree<-function(x) x+3
```

Comment: (+1) It's also easy to call a function in a `within()` statement to create new data.frame column on the fly.

Comment: what the heck is S5?  perhaps you meant ?ReferenceClasses

Comment: @mdsummer Sure; I had an impression it is quite known, but at least it has terrible SEO.

Comment: It was a joke that escaped the zoo

Answer (score 2):

the best approach is to use `mutate()` from dplyr library. Example:

```
addcol = function(dat){
    dat1 = mutate(dat, x2=x1*2)
    return(dat1)
}
```

dat is a data frame with a column named "x1". Use this function `addcol()`, the new dataset now has a new column named "x2" which is twice the value of "x1", assuming `x1` is numeric.