# R: build data frame in user defined function

Tags: r

I've run into a problem in defining a function in R. I'm trying to convert the contents of a `for` loop into a function, so that I can `lapply` the function to a list, (and in turn `mclapply` using the `multicore` package)

I need to build a data frame row by row, taking one text and one numerical value at a time from the function. I understand from a previous post that I must return the values somehow, because of R's pass-and-copy rather than pass-by-reference scheme (see: [How to add a column in the data frame within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359104/how-to-add-a-column-in-the-data-frame-within-a-function)

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
letters <- c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ee')
numbers <- 1:10
madeup <- data.frame(letters, numbers)
output <- data.frame()

functest <- function(x) {
    subtest <- subset(madeup, letters==x)
    if (nrow(subtest==2)){
        calc <- subtest$numbers[2] - subtest$numbers[1]
        ...WHAT GOES HERE?...
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I should do to return `x` and `calc` so that I can then `rbind` these two values each into a new row of the `output` data frame?

If I can copy these two values from the function, I'm imagining the execution command will look something like ---

```
output <- rbind(output, [mc]lapply(letters, functest))
```

--- but am happy to be corrected on this!

Comment: if (nrow(subtest==2)) is probably not what you meant, but it's not really clear anyway - try rephrasing your question so that it is clear what you want the function to do, it looks like you want something to happen if by passing in x, "subtest" is two rows from "madeup", but . . . how about posting the for loop you want to convert so we at least have that?

Comment: @mdsumner Hi - 'if (nrow(subtest==2))' is what i mean

Comment: @mdsumner (oops, didn't realise return adds the comment; apologies .. newbie ..) So, yeah, that if statement is what i mean, and i decided to show an analogy of the for loop, because what i'm working with isn't easily reproducible. All I need is the x values which have 2 rows and the result of the subtraction calculation shown .. so that i can put these in a data frame

Comment: Update the question to be accurate please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rbind`ing `data.frames` is very slow in my experience, but anyway: replace your placeholder with `return(data.frame(x,calc))`.

After changing the function, probably the easiest way to get them all into one `data.fame`is through:

```
output<-do.call(rbind, lapply(letters, functest))
```

Comment: @James - yes you're right, I do do that in my original code, but forgot that step here: i should have added uniqletters <- unique(letters), and then it would be output<-do.call(rbind, lapply(uniqletters, functest))

Comment: Is the 'placeholder' == '*subset*' in the Question Code? If you mean 'x' instead, do mean every one or just the one in `function()`