# Passing data.frame as an argument in function

Tags: r, function

**Context**

As a followup to [R: Pass data.frame by reference to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186633/r-pass-data-frame-by-reference-to-a-function) and [How to add a column in the data frame within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359104/how-to-add-a-column-in-the-data-frame-within-a-function)

I am attempting the following, seemingly easy, function:

```
naToZero <- function(df) {
  df$Vol[is.na(df$Vol)] <- 0
}
```

Data.frame

```
> str(WFM)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   990571 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ Date      : chr  "04/12/2017" "04/12/2017" "04/12/2017" "04/12/2017" ...
 $ Time      :Classes 'hms', 'difftime'  atomic [1:990571] 41970 41969 41968 41967 41966 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ Bar#      : chr  "197953/197953" NA "197952/197953" NA ...
 $ Bar Index : int  0 NA -1 NA NA -2 NA NA -3 NA ...
 $ Tick Range: int  0 NA 0 NA NA 0 NA NA 0 NA ...
 $ Open      : num  33.9 NA 33.9 NA NA ...
 $ High      : num  33.9 NA 33.9 NA NA ...
 $ Low       : num  33.9 NA 33.9 NA NA ...
 $ Close     : num  33.9 NA 33.9 NA NA ...
 $ Vol       : int  100 NA 200 NA NA 100 NA NA 400 NA ...
 $ MACDHist  : num  -59 NA -87 NA NA ...
 $ MACD      : num  -450 NA -445 NA NA ...
 $ MACDSig   : num  -391 NA -358 NA NA ...
 $ ZScore1   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Hoping to use this function to speed things up in data cleaning.

**Problem**

After I run the function in the script editor, and then pass a data.frame to run it. But the function does not do anything and when I View(WFM), it's still the same old data. However, when I manually run the command:

`WFM$Vol[is.na(WFM$Vol)] <- 0`

Then it works.

**Things I tried**

I tried experimenting based on the two links I saw, being seemingly relevant:

Using `WFM <- naToZero(WFM)`, produces a vector with a single value, 0.

Tried using `WFM <- data.table(WFM)` and running the function... same thing.

I must be missing something basic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Virtually all objects in R are immutable: operations do not modify the original, they create a copy. So you need to assign that copy *back to the original*.

`<-` does that, but it assigns to `df` *inside your function*, which is a *copy* of the argument (= `WFM`) you pass to your function.

So you need to modify your function:

```
naToZero <- function(df) {
    df$Vol[is.na(df$Vol)] <- 0
    df
}
```

… and how you call it:

```
WFM = naToZero(WFM)
```

Comment: Interesting mechanics, to clarify my understanding: by adding `df` to the function, we are in essence "bringing the copy to the front", thus making it explicit enough to assign it back to the original via `WFM = naToZero(WFM)`?

Comment: @RobertTan No, it just ensures that the return value of the function call is `df`. Otherwise the return value of the function call is the value of the assignment (`<- 0`), which is the assigned value itself, i.e. 0 (as you have seen).

Comment: The implicit return could be confusing to some, I would have written `return(df)`.

Comment: @DmitriiI. On the contrary! Implicit return is a core semantic in R, which is used ubiquitously. Every R user absolutely needs to be aware of it, and you *should* use it, and [avoid redundant explicit `return()` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968).

Answer (score 4):

We can make this more dynamic using the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`)

```
library(tidyverse)
naToZero <- function(df, Col) {
    Col <- enquo(Col)
    ColN <- quo_name(Col)
     df %>% 
      mutate(!!ColN := replace(!!Col, is.na(!!Col), 0))
 

}

naToZero(WFM, Vol)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#       Date   Vol
#      <chr> <dbl>
#1 04/12/2017     0
#2 04/12/2017    23
#3 04/12/2017    40
```

Or for any other columns

```
naToZero(WFM, Open)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#       Date   Vol  Open
#       <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 04/12/2017    NA  33.9
#2 04/12/2017    23   0.0
#3 04/12/2017    40  32.0
```

The `enquo` does similar functionality as `substitute` from `base R` by taking input arguments and converting it to `quosure`.  In the `mutate`, we can unquote (`!!` or `UQ`) to evaluate the columns as well as the strings on the lhs created with `quo_name`

#### data

```
WFM <- tibble(Date = rep("04/12/2017", 3), Vol = c(NA, 23, 40), Open = c(33.9, NA, 32))
```

Comment: I’m not sure this helps OP … the same could also be achieved (using less code!) with base R. (Although I’m personally a fan of the dplyr version, it goes without saying.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Yes, it could be done, but looking at the OP's dataset, it is derived from `tbl_df`